# Stream with plotly for a long time

Tags: python, streaming, visualization, plotly

I want to use python plotly package to stream data to plot.ly site and visualize there the data.

The feature of my data is that I receive the new value every hour. But if I send the value only every hour plot.ly delete all received data!

My code looks like this:

```
import plotly.plotly as py
py.sign_in(username, api_key)
stream = py.Stream(stream_token)
while True:
    stream.open()
    new_value = get_value()
    date = datetime.datetime.now()
    stream.write({'x': date, 'y': new_value})
    stream.close()
    time.sleep(60 * 60)
```

How to make plot.ly not delete my data?

Comment: right now you are directly using the stream data so every time your loop runs it overwrites data present in  new_value = get_value(). instead of directly assigning the value try to append new data to it

Comment: @nishantkumar this code works fine if I replace `time.sleep(60*60)` to `time.sleep(30)`. So i don't think the problem is there. `get_value()` is the function written by myself.